# Facebook api call in php returns empty

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have result of `$result = $facebook->api($params);` How to extract information from it? Cant decode it using json_decode, gets an error the parameter is string. Searched a lot for the solution, couldn't find any related information.

EDIT

```
$params = array(

 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' => "SELECT uid,pic_square,name,devices FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())",
    );
  $result = $facebook->api($params);
```

Could this return empty? Without showing any error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was testing it using a test user which had no friends. That was the reason why the response was an empty array.

Comment: I'm really to sorry to have posted this question. I'm not deleting it, hoping nobody would waste time if they have a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

A simple debugging technique is to var_dump the variables to see where you're going wrong like so.

```
echo '<pre>'; //just to make the var_dump pretty in the browser
var_dump([variable you want to look into]);
exit(); //does let anything after it display
```

Assuming `$params` is formatted correctly, I would try applying the var_dump to `$result` after the code you just submitted. Then you'll see the format of the string is and hopefully why you aren't able to decode it. The above is a great debugging technique in general.

Comment: array(0) { }  is the output.

Comment: Disclaimer: probably needs someone who's used the Facebook graph API more extensively. Does it return an error if you don't have proper permissions (via access token?) Looking at the basic documentation you could try first replacing the $params with "/me" and see if you get anything from a very basic request.

Comment: Basic requests do work. And its not the permissions.

Comment: Is the Access Token set correctly? What happens if you "echo $facebook->getAccessToken();"? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/)

Comment: That does print out the access token.